# can't get to site

Tags: windows-xp, window

We are on the internet. Everytime we click onto a website in the browser, it takes us to a medical, yellowpages, or other website that has nothing to do with our search. What is the problem?

Comment: is it just one website? if so, which one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

Answer (score 2):

Is your system infected with a virus or malware?  Try scanning your computer with a security application.

Answer (score 0):

Open c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts with notepad. If you see that there are hundreds of hosts that points to 127.0.0.1 and the like you are infected by a virus/trojan/work/botnet/somekindamalware.

Comment: -1 for slagging Windows by suggesting Linux will work better. Regardless of whether this is true or not, it is no help at all and doesn't answer the question.